# jquery file upload progress bar

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I am trying to implement progress bar to my jquery file upload but I am getting exception:

> Multiple directives [progress (module: ui.bootstrap.progressbar),
>   progress (module: blueimp.fileupload)] asking for 'progress'
>   controller on...

Here is my code:

```
<div progress="file.$progress()" class="progress progress-success progress-striped active fade" data-ng-class="{pending:' in'} [file.$state()]">
<div class="bar" data-ng-style="{width: num + '%'}"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add your JS code please.

Comment: I didn't wrote any js for this.. Just jquery-upload-angular.js

Comment: The problem is clear in the error message. The directive progress is available in blueimp as well as ui.bootstrap. So the angular does not know which directive to use.

Comment: How can I specify the one I mean?

Comment: The perils of mixing jquery in with your angular app.  If you're going to do angular then you need to drink the koolaid and go all angular.